# Serialization exception in wcf service

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization

We have a wcf service containing some methods and occasionally it failes when it tries to serialize the data. The exception is below(Also contains the stack trace).

Any solution for this ?
Also, Why does this happen sporadically not all the time ? The data that is returned remains the same all the time.

[System.Text.EncoderFallbackException]: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDF98 at index 1 to specified code page.
CallStack:
    at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(System.Char charUnknown,System.Int32 index) [IL: 0x2B][Native: 0xB7]
    at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(System.Char ch,System.Char*& chars) [IL: 0xE7][Native: 0x125]
    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(System.Char* chars,System.Int32 charCount,System.Byte* bytes,System.Int32 byteCount,System.Text.EncoderNLS baseEncoder) [IL: 0x21D][Native: 0xD93D94]
    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(System.Char* chars,System.Int32 charCount,System.Byte* bytes,System.Int32 byteCount) [IL: 0x54][Native: 0x4C]
    at System.Xml.XmlStreamNodeWriter.UnsafeGetUTF8Chars(System.Char* chars,System.Int32 charCount,System.Byte[] buffer,System.Int32 offset) [IL: 0x80][Native: 0x263CC3]
    at System.Xml.XmlBinaryNodeWriter.UnsafeWriteText(System.Char* chars,System.Int32 charCount) [IL: 0x3C][Native: 0x8B]
    at System.Xml.XmlBinaryNodeWriter.WriteText(System.String value) [IL: 0x39][Native: 0x3C]
    at System.Xml.XmlBaseWriter.WriteString(System.String value) [IL: 0x4D][Native: 0x9E]
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteString(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter,System.String value,System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString name,System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString ns) [IL: 0x29][Native: 0x53]
    at WriteArrayOfstringToXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator ,System.Object ,System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext ,System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract )[Native: 0xDC]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below url, might help you with this exception

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/063579c4-f0ed-465a-acb1-d72a84e6b3fb/encoderfallbackexception-on-binaryencoder-tcp?forum=wcf